# Is it possible for a drip irrigation pressure regulator to do its job without dripping or spraying water?

Tags: water, irrigation, gardening

We have high pressure at our house and I'm trying to have a drip irrigation setup with low flow.  The pressure regulator has a pretty decent stream of water coming out from the relief hole when the system is running.  There are more expensive regulators on the market, but thinking of the physics of the situation, doesn't the excess pressure need be relieved somewhere?  Is it physically possible to "regulate" the pressure without losing water?

And as a follow up question, assuming I'm right above, is there an alternative way to make my system work without losing excess water?  At full pressure, the ends and attachment points are prone to separating, so I don't really want to forego some form of pressure control.

Comment: My pressure regulators don’t leak, either for the drip system or the house.

Comment: I'm no expert, but  I'd saw that if your PRV is leaking, it's because a seal has failed. That shouldn't be a normal mode of operation.

Comment: If the whoke house suffers high pressure, fit a pressure regulator.

Comment: What is "high pressure at your house," as a number with pressure units? What is the specific regulator model?

Comment: I don't have an appropriate gauge to measure, I just know that when we moved here we noticed that the shower could peel the skin off your back if you picked the wrong head.  Slight exaggeration, but not much.  The regulator is a black rain bird from Home Depot or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The physics of the situation (handled correctly) are that the pressure regulator is a valve (no leak required) which has a fixed or adjustable spring pushing it open.

When the regulated water pressure is below the setting of the spring, water flows through. When the regulated  water pressure is above the setting of the spring, water flow stops, via the regulated water pressure pushing against the spring to close the valve. Between those two points, the valve is partially open.

If it's leaking outside the valve, there is typically a hole in a diaphragm that's not supposed to have a hole in it. There should be rebuild kits available (which include a new diaphragm, and some other parts) unless it's a throwaway (*i.e.* not made to be serviced) plastic version. Not all plastic versions are throwaways, but in my experience all throwaways are plastic.

Comment: Yeah, the thing I didn't think of correctly is that so long as the orifice within the valve is smaller (so to speak) than the openings downstream, the pressure can be reduced.  If the downstream is fully blocked, the pressure will eventually equalize regardless of the size of the orifice (except fully closed).  Static vs. dynamic.  The chintzy valve I had had a pressure relief hole in the side which was leaking, not sure it's design purpose.  I decided to just purchase a higher quality unit.